# Move Aosp emulator image from terminal server to a development machine

Tags: android, build, kernel, android-source

i'm sitting here at problem now for two weeks and can't quiet figure it out...

For some researches I want to build the mini_emulator_x86-eng on a terminal server and after that copy it to my laptop and run it.

I use a terminalserver for my aosp builds with the newest version "android-8.0.0_r4", because it has much more resources then my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04 with the newest Android Studio).

So I build the files and the copy the .img files + kernel from the out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86/ folder and my avd folder .android/avd/own.avd/.
In the avd folder there is also my config file, which looks like this:

### config.ini

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=x86
hw.cpu.arch=x86
image.sysdir.1=/home/olsk7422/.android/avd/own.avd/
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
```

After the Emulator start with

```
AEmulator -kernel ./kernel -system  ./system.img -ramdisk ./ramdisk.img -avd own -show-kernel
```

It shows this and stops:

[link](https://pastebin.com/edVepsd6)

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

I tried also all the other kernels in the prebuild folder, unfortunately no one works ...